# List of values from list of jsons

Tags: python, json, list

I would like to extract from this kind of list:

```
[{'time': '2018-10-08T13:26:40.366296729Z', 'ask0': 6604.036},
{'time': '2018-10-08T13:26:45.666245795Z', 'ask0': 6607.34909},
{'time': '2018-10-08T13:26:51.08045435Z', 'ask0': 6607.18674}]
```

Is there any possibility to create list of asks0 in one line? I tried something like that:

```
asks = [y for x, y in points.__iter__()]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: what is `points`?

Answer (score 4):

```
data = [
    {"time": "2018-10-08T13:26:40.366296729Z", "ask0": 6604.036},
    {"time": "2018-10-08T13:26:45.666245795Z", "ask0": 6607.34909},
    {"time": "2018-10-08T13:26:51.08045435Z", "ask0": 6607.18674},
]

asks = [d["ask0"] for d in data]

# asks will be [6604.036, 6607.34909, 6607.18674]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
points = [{'time': '2018-10-08T13:26:40.366296729Z', 'ask0': 6604.036},
{'time': '2018-10-08T13:26:45.666245795Z', 'ask0': 6607.34909},
{'time': '2018-10-08T13:26:51.08045435Z', 'ask0': 6607.18674}]

[i['ask0'] for i in points]
#[6604.036, 6607.34909, 6607.18674]
```